# SQL query to find which name contains first and last letters from your name

Tags: sql

I need help to write a query to find names from a given column which contains first and last letters from your name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: From my name. How come you want that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [SQL wildcards](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)

For example

```
select * from table_name where first_name like 'M%i'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to check it.

```
select * from table where (name like 'yourfirstletter%' or name like '%yourlastletter')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

select col_name from table_name where (first_name like 'FirstLetterOfYourName%' AND last_name like '%LastLetterOfYourName');